# Using Python's Face Recognition library in Android

Tags: java, android, python, android-studio, face-recognition

I want to implement face recognition functionality in my android app. I found out that there is a library [face_recognition](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/face_recognition) in Python. 
I have successfully installed the library and its working fine. Now I want to use that library in the Android Studio. I don't know how to proceed and import or call the python files using Java in Android studio. Can someone guide me how to proceed?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to use Python in the Android Studio? That might not be possible.

What you can do is develop the python module/functionality in a python environment - either using an editor and executing the script from the command line, or some other IDE supporting Python.

Next step is to call the package in java, as you would call it in the command line:

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process pr = rt.exec("python myPythonScript.py [arguments]");
```